# A formula for counting cells with zero value in cells D1:O1 before reaching value greater than zero

Tags: excel

I have data laid out across columns called months, I need to count number of cells with zero value, but only keep counting until you reach the last cell with a value greater than zero, don’t count zero value cells after the last cell with value greater than zero.

The cells in question are D1:O1

I tried finding the answer on this forum but I couldn’t find anything that worked.

Comment: What about countifs() with 2 criteria: =0 and not blank.

Comment: Are you saying that "0,0,-1,0,0,0" should return 3 and "0,0,1,0,0,0" should return 2?

Comment: Please provide an input sample and expected output in table [markdown format](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the specific case, you can use the following if all number are zero or positives:

```
=MATCH(0, D1:O1)
```

If you have negative value next to the last zero in your range, because `MATCH` with `match_type` equal to `1` (default) the range needs to be in ascending order, you can use:

```
=MATCH(0, ABS(D1:O1))
```

which works in a general case

Previous approaches **assume you are counting until you find a value different than zero**.

Without input sample, I am not 100% you mean from your question to stop when it finds a value *different than zero or greater than zero*.  For the later case. You need to keep counting zero values even if it finds negative values and stop counting when it finds a positive value. If that is the case, then try the following:

```
=LET(rng, D1:O1, seq, SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(rng)),f, FILTER(seq, rng > 0,-1), 
 pos, IF(@f=-1, MAX(seq) + 1, TAKE(f,,1)), IF(pos = 1, 0, 
 REDUCE(0, FILTER(rng, seq < pos), LAMBDA(ac,x, IF(x = 0, ac + 1, ac)))))
```

It considers several non happy path scenarios:

1. All values are positives, returns `0`
2. The first value is positive, returns `0`.
3. No positive values found, counts to the end

Otherwise it finds the index position of the first positive value (`pos`), then counts zero values before such index position via `REDUCE` function.